# toArray is switching the "Create_at" and "Update_at" of a model when using "getCreatedAtAttribute" and "getUpdatedAtAttribute"

Tags: laravel

I have the following model:

```
abstract class ApiObjectModel extends Model
{
  protected $appends = ['unique', 'created_by', 'updated_by'];
  protected $hidden = ['deleted_at', 'head', 'create_id', 'update_id', 'createdByUser', 'updatedByUser'];


  protected $casts = [
    'created_at' => 'datetime:Y-m-d h:m',
    'updated_at' => 'datetime:Y-m-d h:m',
  ];

  /*
   * other stuff
   */

  public function getCreatedAtAttribute($value)
  {
    return Carbon::parse($value)->diffForHumans();
  }

  public function getUpdatedAtAttribute($value)
  {
    return Carbon::parse($value)->diffForHumans();
  }
}
```

and this class:

```
class Ticket extends ApiObjectModel
{
  protected $table = 'Ticket';
  protected $fillable = ['Title', 'Description'];

}
```

I am running the following Test:

```
/** @test **/
public function updating_an_object_changes_the_update_at_time()
{
    $response = $this->post('api/ticket', $this->basic_data());
    //prüft Json
    $response->assertJsonFragment([
        'created_at' => $this->createtime,
        'updated_at' => $this->createtime,
        'created_by' => User::first()->name,
        'updated_by' => User::first()->name,
    ]);

    Carbon::setTestNow(Carbon::getTestNow()->addMinutes(30));

    $response = $this->put('api/ticket/1', [
        'Title' => 'Update'
    ]);

    $response->assertJsonFragment([
        'created_at' => $this->createtime,
        'updated_at' => Carbon::getTestNow()->addMinutes(30)->diffForHumans(),
        'created_by' => User::first()->name,
        'updated_by' => User::first()->name,
    ]);
}
```

**The Test fails because the `created_at` and the `updated_at` values are switched.**

In my Controller, after doing some debug work, I found out the following result basically one line after the other:

```
dump(Ticket::findOrFail($id)) 

Result:

...
#attributes: array:8 [
 "id" => 1
 "Title" => "Update"
 "Description" => "Change Description"
 "create_id" => 1
 "update_id" => 1
 "created_at" => "2030-02-10 12:00:00"
 "updated_at" => "2030-02-10 12:30:00"
 "deleted_at" => null
]
...

dd(Ticket::findOrFail($id)->toArray()) 

Result:

array:8 [
  "id" => 1
  "Title" => "Update"
  "Description" => "Change Description"
  "created_at" => "30 minutes ago"
  "updated_at" => "1 second ago"
  "unique" => 1
  "created_by" => "Test User 1"
  "updated_by" => "Test User 1"
]
```

Can somebody help me understand and debug this?

(Laravel Framework 6.1.0)

Comment: ahhh... I found the problem! I was testing this wrong! The times are right! arghhh.

Answer (score 0):

nevermind... I was confusing the difftohuman() values from Carbon and set up the tests wrong.

This just passed:

```
/** @test **/
public function updating_an_object_changes_the_update_at_time()
{
    $response = $this->post('api/ticket', $this->basic_data());
    //prüft Json
    $response->assertJsonFragment([
        'created_at' => $this->createtime,
        'updated_at' => $this->createtime,
        'created_by' => User::first()->name,
        'updated_by' => User::first()->name,
    ]);

    Carbon::setTestNow(Carbon::getTestNow()->addMinutes(30));

    $response = $this->put('api/ticket/1', [
        'Title' => 'Update'
    ]);

    $response->assertJsonFragment([
        // following two lines got changed:
        'created_at' => Carbon::now()->subMinutes(30)->diffForHumans(),
        'updated_at' => Carbon::now()->diffForHumans(),
        'created_by' => User::first()->name,
        'updated_by' => User::first()->name,
    ]);
}
```

If you have other ideas how to spend your thoughts in circles... let me know